# JSON and Iphone table loading, I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when scrolling

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview

I'm having a bear of a time trying to figure out why I'm getting a EXC_BAD ACCESS error. The console is giving me this eror: " -[CFArray objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3b14110", I Can't figure it out...Thanks in advance.

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [rowsArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.
NSDictionary *dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"age"];


return cell;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:207.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"NOW", @"NOW");
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.1.8/~imac/iphone/jsontest.php"];
NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

//  NSLog(jsonreturn); // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are

NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;

// In "real" code you should surround this with try and catch
NSDictionary * dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
if (dict)
{
    rowsArray = [dict objectForKey:@"member"];
}

NSLog(@"Array: %@",rowsArray);
    NSLog(@"count is: %i", [self.rowsArray count]);


[jsonreturn release];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    }

 @end
```

Comment: On which line does the crash happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `rows` is an instance variable that holds the data you want to display? If so, you're not retaining it when you assign it. Remember: if you want to keep an object, you have to claim ownership of it. The way to do this is either to allocate it yourself or `retain`/`copy` an object allocated elsewhere.

This assignment

```
rows = [dict objectForKey:@"member"];
```

doesn't do that. That means `rows` is getting deallocated and eventually holds a reference to a deallocated object.

Also, what's the difference between `rowsArray` and `rows`? How can you be sure that `rowsArray` returns the same `count` as `rows`? Generally, you should use the same data source in all of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods.